# Landsat 8 - Collection 1 BQA vs Collection 2 QA_PIXEL

Tags: landsat-8, atmospheric-correction, data-quality

I am working on updating a Python program for atmospherically correcting Level 1 Landsat 8 data from Collection 1 to Collection 2, as Collection 1 data is discontinued and will no longer be available from USGS past December of this year.

However, the Collection 1 Level 1 dataset contains a single QA file, which is the BQA.tif. The Collection 2 Level 1 dataset contains two QA files, QA_PIXEL.tif and QA_RADSAT.tif. I have looked through the documentation, but I am a bit new at this and don't understand where the differences lie. Is the QA_PIXEL.tif file from C2 functionally the same as the BQA.tif file from C1? What should I be doing to convert the use of the BQA.tif file to the QA file(s) available from Collection 2?

For context, here is the use of the code in the script for processing with Collection 1 data:

```
ds = gdal.Open(**BQA.tif)
flags = ds.ReadAsArray()[self.sline:self.eline,self.spixl:self.epixl]
ds = None
cloud = np.bitwise_and(flags,int('101010000',2)) #mask cloud and could shadows
self.cloud = cloud > 0
```